# Move Azure SQL database server between subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, azure

We have two subscriptions (DEV and PROD). A database server has been deployed to the DEV subscription, but it is now in use by our production system. I want to move the Azure SQL database server to the PROD environment.

I have owner privilege on both the DEV and PROD environment, but when I try to move the Azure SQL Server then the PROD environment doesn't show in the list of subscriptions. This [feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/moving-sql-azure-servers-between-subscriptions/) has been implemented in 2012 and I do see the 'subscriptions' combo, so I think it should be possible. Anyone has a hint?

Comment: have you added in the subscriptions under the same account https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/02/03/how-to-manage-multiple-windows-azure-subscriptions/

Comment: You're right... The problem is that the two subscriptions use a different Azure directory. I probably need to move the subscription to the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I found was Export to Blob from the source *database*

[SQL Database Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwbsE.png)

Transfer the file from One subscription to another blob storage on the target subscription

Then on the target *SQL Server* Import the database from the blob storage

[SQL Server Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn7aX.png)

Comment: On Stack it is preferred that you describe the solution completely within the answer so that even if the referenced link or pictures are removed that the information will remain available. Simply creating your own pictures is not a substitute to accurately describing the solution. If you pull information out of a source document it is appropriate to provide and attribution link to that source.

Answer (score -3):

Hope you have fixed this issue, in case if you still need a help. please follow the below link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources